# Java - Live Streaming Video which uploaded to Database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I think the title says all, but here's what I've done so far:

1. I managed to upload video to MySQL with Large Blob
2. Currently, I also managed to stream the video, but this way take 2 steps, which is:
   First: I extract the blob into local directory
   Second: I use that directory path as src in my video playing page.

Now that my lecturer wants it without extracting to local disk first, he wants to live streaming from database. I only managed to do this if it's a picture, but a video I don't get any clue.

I hope anybody could help me or at least give me clues, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be a good place to start from:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577307/video-download-stream-using-java-servlet)

Also, if you are just downloading the file, [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-to-download-file-from-database) link might help.

And if you have your own software on the clients side to show the stream, I would suggest that you will open a socket between the client and server and then just sent the video in pieces.